# SQL query to find missing values in tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table 1

```
Product    product Description
ABC        Hardware
CBD        Software
BCQ        Component
DEF        License
```

Table 2

```
Product  Product Description Order ID
ABC      Hardware            1234
ABC      Hardware            2345
ABC      Hardware            5678
BCQ      Component           7896
BCQ      Component           9681
```

Here is the background
table 1 has the product data, table 2 has the product data with order ids
I want to know how many products are not ordered (in this scenario "CBD     Software" and "DEF     License" has not orders placed hence is missing in table 2).
now i want to know how many products were never placed on an order.

Comment: Request you to please accept the answer as it motivate me to answer more questions.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the below query

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
where ProductId not in (SELECT ProductId FROM ProductDescription)
```

Below is the actual example

```
Create table ProductDescription (ProdCd varchar(10), ProdDes Varchar(20))
insert into ProductDescription values ('ABC', 'Hardware'),
('CBD',     'Software'),
('BCQ',     'Component'),
('DEF',     'License')

Create table ProductOrders (ProdCd varchar(10), ProdDes Varchar(20), OrderId int)
insert into ProductOrders values ('ABC',      'Hardware',      1234),
('ABC',      'Hardware',      2345),
('ABC',      'Hardware',      5678),
('BCQ',      'Component',     7896),
('BCQ',      'Component',     9681)

SELECT * FROM ProductDescription
where ProdCd not in (SELECT ProdCd FROM ProductOrders)
```

The output is as shown below

```
ProdCd  ProdDes
---------------
CBD     Software
DEF     License
```

You can find the live demo here [**Live Demo**](https://rextester.com/HUWSK94825)

Answer (score 2):

Do you just want `not exists`?

```
select p.*
from products p
where not exists (select 1 from orders o where o.product = p.product);
```

Comment: You forgot the `orders` alias `o`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `LEFT JOIN` and `IS NULL` in `where` condition

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.product = t1.product
WHERE t2.product IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet another way, with `RIGHT JOIN` and `IS NULL`:

```
declare @prod table
(
    Product varchar(100),
    [product Description] varchar(100)
)

insert into @prod
select 'ABC','Hardware' union
select 'CBD','Software' union
select 'BCQ','Component' union
select 'DEF','License'


declare @prodOrders table
(
    Product varchar(100),
    [product Description] varchar(100),
    [orderid] int
)
insert into @prodOrders
select 'ABC','Hardware',1234  union
select 'ABC','Hardware',2345  union
select 'ABC','Hardware',5678  union
select 'BCQ','Component',7896 union
select 'BCQ','Component',9681

SELECT t1.*
FROM @prodOrders t2 
right JOIN @prod t1 ON t2.product = t1.product
WHERE t2.product IS NULL
```

[**Live Demo**](https://rextester.com/RXQI95877)